# Comma before ‘with love’

Tags: commas

Is it necessary to add a comma in: ‘To Dad, with love’ or can it be ‘To Dad with love’? Especially if this going to be a title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titles can be flexible.

Compare the book title *[From Russia, with Love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Russia,_with_Love_(novel))* with a comma

and the related film *[From Russia with Love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Russia_with_Love_(film))* without a comma.

In such a verbless sentence, I would personally prefer a comma but would not see it as obligatory.